# Template Matrix scalar multiplication c++

Tags: c++

When I try to compile the following coding, I have get an error saying

**Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Matrix __cdecl operator*(int const &,class Matrix &)" (??D@YA?AV?$Matrix@H$02$01@@ABHAAV0@@Z) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Homework4\Homework4\main.obj  Homework4**

This error is occurred from the scalar multiplication on matrix and I don't know how to fix it.  Can anyone give me an advice on this?

```
//Matrix.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T, int m, int n>
class Matrix
{
vector<vector<T>> elements;
int nrow;
int ncol;

public:
Matrix();
~Matrix();
void print();
vector<T> row(int);
vector<T> col(int);

friend Matrix<T, m, n> operator+<>(const Matrix<T, m, n>&, const Matrix<T, m, n>&);
friend Matrix<T, m, n> operator-<>(const Matrix<T, m, n>&, const Matrix<T, m, n>&);
friend Matrix<T, m, n> operator*(const T&, Matrix<T, m, n>&);

};

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n>::Matrix() : nrow(m), ncol(n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++){
    vector<T> row(ncol, i);
    elements.push_back(row);
}
}

template<class T,int m,int n>
vector<T> Matrix<T, m, n>::row(int i)
{
return elements[i];
}

template<class T, int m, int n>
vector<T> Matrix<T, m, n>::col(int j)
{
vector<T> col;
for (int i = 0; i < ncol; i++)
{
    col.push_back(elements[i][j]);
}
return col;
}

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n>::~Matrix(){}

template<class T, int m, int n>
void Matrix<T, m, n>::print()
{
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
    {
        cout << elements[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n> operator+(const Matrix<T, m, n>& m1, const Matrix<T, m, n>& m2){
Matrix<T, m, n> m3;
int nrow = m1.nrow;
int ncol = m1.ncol;
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j){
        m3.elements[i][j] = m1.elements[i][j] + m2.elements[i][j];
    }
}

return m3;
}

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n> operator-(const Matrix<T, m, n>& m1, const Matrix<T, m, n>& m2){
Matrix<T, m, n> m3;
int nrow = m1.nrow;
int ncol = m1.ncol;
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j){
        m3.elements[i][j] = m1.elements[i][j] - m2.elements[i][j];
    }
}

return m3;
}


template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n> operator*(const T& c, const Matrix<T, m, n>& m1){
int nrow = m1.nrow;
int ncol = m1.ncol;
Matrix<T, m, n> m2;
for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; ++j){
        m2.elements[i][j] = c*m1.elements[i][j];
    }
}
return m2;
}

//main.cpp
#include "Matrix.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Matrix<int, 3, 2> a;
Matrix<int, 3, 2> b;
Matrix<int, 3, 2> c;
c = 2*b;

c.print();  
}
```

I think the error comes from the friend function (operation *) in the body of the class, but I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because
a) `operator*` is declared as non-template (you should use `<>`)
b) if you use `<>` syntax, you must provide the declaration of the template.

Fix
(Add before Matrix class):

```
template<class T, int m, int n>
class Matrix;

template<class T, int m, int n>
Matrix<T, m, n> operator*(T&, const Matrix<T, m, n>&);

//class matrix definition here
```

Add `<>` to `operator*` `friend` declaration:

```
friend Matrix<T, m, n> operator*<>(T&, const Matrix<T, m, n>&);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Unfortunately, I did what you told me to do and it still gives me an error.  I removed the "const" from "const T&" also added <>.  Also, I added the top four lines. Can you give me an advice on that?

Comment: Can you tell me why do I have to make another operator* overloading at the top?  I already made a friend function and I don't know why i need that one.

Comment: Your friend declaration in class is befriending single instantiation of `operator*` template. For example `template<class T> class A{};` is template, and `A<int>` is instantiation. The same goes for the `operator*` Instantiation cannot be created without primary template. It's like saying `A<int>` without knowing that `A` is template. `operator*` is instantiated in your class everytime you make an instantiation of your class, simply by replacing `T`, `m` and `n` with actual type and values, so saying strictly you make a friend of a single function, not a template.

Comment: I get it now.  Thank you so much for the easy explanation^^